# Read metadata from a PNG file with imagemagick++

Tags: imagemagick, png, metadata

I want to do this (as subject indicates) using the imagemagick++ API.  I specifically want to read the focal length used by the (DSLR camera) to shoot. **[EDIT]** This is part of a program that manipulates the images **[END EDIT]**

I know I can do it through a system call, invoking the command `identify -verbose <image_filename>` (e.g., with `popen` so that I can read the output and look for the line containing `FocalLengthIn35mmFilm`). But this is gross for two reasons:

- It is just gross and inefficient.
- `identify` is an `ImageMagick` utility, so if that command can do it, then I should be able to do it using ImageMagick's API.

Notice that, as the subject says, I am working with PNG files;  however, a solution that could work with any lossless image format would be preferred.

Comment: If you just want the metadata and not the entire Magick++ dev suite and its image processing capabilities, you may find `exiv2` lighter weight... https://exiv2.org/examples.html

Comment: Good point, and I wasn't explicit in my OP  (I just edited it to indicate that I do need to manipulate the images, which is the reason why I'm using imagemagick's API)

Comment: Obviously I have no idea how much processing you need to do on your images, but you may find the fairly comprehensive features in **CImg** at http://cimg.eu are plenty for your needs and very light weight since it is just a single include file with no libraries to link. It may be that **CImg** coupled with **exiv2** is a solution. Please don't misunderstand me, I am not trying to suggest in any way that you should not use **Magick++**, I am just exploring alternative possibilities.

Comment: Any "heavy" processing I'm doing takes place after I have access to the value of pixels as function of (x,y);  of course, I also need to read from the PNG file and write the resulting PNG output.  Fairly basic as far as the image library goes.   However, I will say that although the pointer is appreciated (I will be sure to investigate this CImg library), inertia is a very powerful thing, and the basic version of my program already uses imgmagick++;  CImg does not solve the issue at hand (since I would have to use exiv2 in addition), so I'll stick to imgmagick++ for now.

Comment: FWIW, I already added the `popen` / `identify -verbose ...` code and successfully obtained the focal length in my current "develop branch" of the program;  I would very much like to implement this through the API;  but worse come to worst, I can just leave it with the `popen` / `identify -verbose` approach, even if I find it ugly  (it works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageMagick is not a EXIF editor, so the best option is to dump the profile EXIF payload into libexif API. But if you are just peaking at a value, you can use ImageMagick's [percent escape](https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) mechanics to retrieve a value.

For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Magick++.h>

using namespace Magick;

int main()
{
    InitializeMagick((const char *)nullptr);
    Image img("DSCF2763.JPG");
    Blob data;
    MagickCore::SetImageOption(img.imageInfo(), "format", "%[EXIF:FocalLengthIn35mmFilm]");
    img.write(&data, "INFO");
    std::string value((const char *)data.data(), data.length());
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

The above is the same as the CLI command:

```
convert DSCF2763.JPG -define "format=%[EXIF:FocalLengthIn35mmFilm]" info:
```

### Update

An even easier way would be to use `Magick::Image.attribute()`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Magick++.h>

using namespace Magick;

int main()
{
    InitializeMagick((const char *)nullptr);
    Image img("DSCF2763.JPG");
    std::string value = img.attribute("EXIF:FocalLengthIn35mmFilm");
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This second version seems cleaner (simpler anyway).  At first, I thought it might not work, because of the EXIF (I had the idea that EXIF was a JPEG-specific thing), but I just tried, and it works like a charm!